# Laravel BotManStudio with Telegram doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel-5, telegram-bot

Help me please. Now i'm playing around Botman Studio in Larvel. I'm using cod from example. It works great with web interface. I want use it with Telegram. I install drivers, get token. When i try to get registration this way:
"php artisan botman:telegram:register"
It gets error:

*ErrorException  : file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook?url=https://83255e3c.ngrok.io/botman): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found*

Web interface work well with https://83255e3c.ngrok.io/botman/tinker (it use same webhook).

I register webhook on telegram this way: 
curl -d "url=https://83255e3c.ngrok.io/botman" "https://api.telegram.org/bot524662111:AAF3syuVVVVVVVVV35Goh4lR6pxx1yLY/setWebhook"

Telegram told me Ok.
Now i send message to bot using telegram. 
I see in ngrok's logo it comes as well as from webinteface, but bot doesn't reply. And he does work well wen i send message through web.

Help me please and sorry for my english. I will study hard. I promise.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message you can see, that the YOUR-TELEGRAM-TOKEN didn't set.
The link should be like:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR-TELEGRAM-TOKEN>/setWebhook?url=https://83255e3c.ngrok.io/botman
```

Try set token on configuration:

> you can find the configuration file located under config/botman/telegram.php

You can find it in the official documentation https://botman.io/2.0/driver-telegram

Answer (score 0):

write below code in .env file:

TELEGRAM_TOKEN=telegram bot token here